# How to check if sitemap index has been successfully submitted and can be properly read

Tags: seo, google-search-console, googlebot, sitemap, xml-sitemap

Recently, I have submitted a sitemap index with a slew of xml files and URL links.

I see that the sitemap index has been successfully submitted and I understand that the discovered URLs is possible to be '0' even if the sitemap index can be read.

I was just wondering if it is possible to test that my sitemap index is being read correctly?
That is if I can test an xml file or a URL link in the sitemap index to see if it is being read correctly and it is available for use for when the Google Bot wants to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the Status column?  It should show "Success" if Google reads it correctly as well as the last date Google read your sitemap.

Just as an FYI, there's lots of comments here regarding the [Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox).  It might be beneficial for you to read through that discussion.